# LLDB displays wrong line for the provided function name

Tags: macos, lldb

Below is the sample source used for debugging test

```
#include <stdio.h>
int k() {
  puts("test");
  // above line repeats to certain amounts
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  puts("test");
  // above line repeats to certain amounts
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled above with :
`clang -g -o test test.c`

When I run `list main` in the LLDB prompt, LLDB shows the lines that are part of the `int k() {...}`. Even the first line of `int main() {...}` is not shown.

Even more weird, LLDB sets correct breakpoint for the symbol `main`.

What's going on with LLDB???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, I see:

```
(lldb) list main
File: /tmp/test.c
   3      puts("test");
   4      // above line repeats to certain amounts
   5      return 0;
   6    }
   7    
   8    int main() {
   9      puts("test");
   10     // above line repeats to certain amounts
   11     return 0;
   12   }
```

When lldb lists a function by name, it shows a window around the symbol name, because often times people put the return type on a separate line from the function name, but the function name's line number is always where the debug information tells lldb the function is.  This way you can see the whole function definition.  But the actual name should be roughly in the middle of the listing.

Note also that the list command auto-repeat will continue the listing, so you can just keep hitting Return (which auto-repeats the last command) to see more of your source.

If that's not what you see, first try running `lldb -x` to make sure that you don't have something in your .lldbinit that is affecting this.

If that still doesn't help, please file a bug with http://bugs.llvm.org.

Comment: Could you try with longer source? Add at least 15 more lines to `k` and `main`. What do you see? I just want to know what the other macs behave.

Comment: I added a bunch of lines to main and k and added some other functions, and the "main" line is slightly below the midpoint just like above.  Note, there is a known bug with lldb (or clang, I'm not sure which yet) where listing a function name lists the declaration of the function rather than its definition source lines.  E.g. if the declaration is in a .h file it will list the lines from the .h file.  Maybe you are seeing that?

Comment: No, I didn't get what you got from your lldb. I did exactly `list main` and my lldb show the line at the middle of `int k()`

Comment: At this point it's probably best to file a bug.  Be sure to provide the version of lldb & clang that you are using.